# Can we have a community wiki page on "The Definitive Python Book Guide and List"

Tags: discussion

I was looking up for some question like

*[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)*

on Stack Overflow aimed for **Python 2** and **Python 3**

---

I found the below link (locked and closed since 2011).

*[What is the best quick-read Python book out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570/what-is-the-best-quick-read-python-book-out-there)*

This link below (closed since 2015)

*[Which Python book would you recommend for a Linux Sysadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171835/which-python-book-would-you-recommend-for-a-linux-sysadmin)*

This link below (closed since 2012)

*[Books for OpenCV and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677317/books-for-opencv-and-python)*

---

Can Stack Overflow please have a community wiki page like *[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)* for **Python** covering books on **Python 2** and **Python 3** for beginner to intermediate to advanced level?

The best thing about this is that it gets updates now and then, (that page was last updated just yesterday), so people have the list of books to choose from (according to their level of understanding i.e beginner or advanced) in one place.

Comment: The C++ list is a bit of an anomaly. It exists and is allowed to exist because the C++ community promised (and has largely kept their promise) to maintain it scrupulously. Unless you can get the same guarantee from the Python community, I don't think this is going to happen. (Also, for what it's worth, most of the updates to the C++ book list are terrible and rolled back...)

Comment: I'd request Python enthusiast community to please make this happen because it really helps us beginners to move a level up in short time rather than wasting time reading crab books. No one has an idea before reading if a book is worth. Your experience with books would really help others.

Comment: That info should be in the tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info which it, by the looks of it, already is.

Comment: I'd also suggest popping by the Python chat room and/or checking out https://sopython.com/wiki/. It's a community driven project to try to keep a list of canonical questions/answers as well as reading material/misc things that don't quite work well in SO's Q&A format.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being voted down ! :-/

Comment: Because users don't want such Community Wiki created for Python, also [voting on meta is different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @rene Python tag wiki doesn't mention what book is best suited for beginners, or intermediate or advanced users

Comment: Well, hop in the Python chatroom and ask if that is a valuable addition and if it is, edit it in ..

Comment: What's wrong with https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut it is worth noting to you that here on meta, votes are usually distributed based on opinion of your question, not based on the validity of it being a 'good' or 'bad' question. The downvotes signify more people dislike the idea and it does not mean it is a bad question as much as it does on the main page. (OH now i see rene's explanation...)

Comment: @Braiam That's super awesome, thanks for mentioning..

Comment: @JonClements Are there other SO communities also for different programming languages? Like SOhaskell, or SOc (for c++ and c), SOx86 (for x86 assembly) and many other languages ? How did you know about this SO community? It is not listed anywhere on StackExchange website. Do you know of any other ?

Comment: @CodyGray I'd like to see your comment as an answer - that the C++ book list is an exception, allowed because the C++ community made a promise and is actively keeping it. People will continue to ask for book lists for any major technology in the future, citing the C++ book list. Therefore I believe it would be good to have this exceptional status documented here on MSO.

Comment: @Braiam the link you provided may have been removed. Can you provide the updated link?

Comment: @DebarthaPaul Wasn't hard to find, had to tried searching.. https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/books/free-programming-books.md

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with this.

Because

1. Asking to recommend books or tools or resources are off topic to SO mainly because they invite spams.

You said that

> I found the below link (locked and closed since 2011)
>
> [What is the best quick-read Python book out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570/what-is-the-best-quick-read-python-book-out-there)

The lock reason is saying why it's locked.

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.** This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

This is not considered as a good on topic question.

So having such community wiki are bad idea. Contents like that may be included in the tag wiki ( there are many tag wiki's containing links to external resources)

Comment: *"Asking to recommend books or tools or resources are off topic to SO mainly because they invite spams."* Oh, and **do they**! I always believed this to be true because it's logical, but since becoming a moderator, I see first-hand evidence of it constantly. Virtually all the spam and low-quality answers we get are on these types of questions, and handling them correctly means closing/deleting the question more so than deleting the offending answer(s).